# ORDER BY date while also using LIMIT in a MySQL query - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, sql-order-by

HI,

I can't quite figure this out, I'm trying to pull records from MySQL, order them reverse-chronologically and limit the results to four per page (and using pagination to organize the pages). It is currently returning this error:

Fatal error: SQL in /Users/allan/Sites/4is_site/casestudylist.php on line 126

```
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;
$query = "SELECT * FROM studies  ORDER BY date desc WHERE niche = '{$_GET['niche']}' $limit";
```

The pagination has been working fine, just now that I've tried to add the ORDER BY that I'm getting problems.

Comment: Also, I've heard that I need to escape this: '{$_GET['niche']}', how do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

That syntax is incorrect. This should work.

```
$escapedNiche = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['niche']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM studies WHERE niche = '$escapedNiche' ".
         "ORDER BY date DESC $limit";
```

For future reference - [SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

BTW To escape $_GET['niche']:

```
$clean_niche = mysql_escape_string($_GET['niche']);
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;
$query = "SELECT * FROM studies  "
        ."WHERE niche = '{$clean_niche}' "
        ."ORDER BY date desc $limit";
```

This will help to protect you from SQL injection attacks by escaping the characters in $_GET['niche'].

For extra security, consider using bound parameters (google'em) and/or library functions like Zend DB to access the database.

Comment: mysql_escape_string only sanitizes input if the input is surrounded by quotes. To sanitize a limit you can verify the 'niche' param is an integer using is_numeric().